# What does # mean in ls output

Tags: terminal, ls

when I do an ls on a director I get an output like

```
xxxx@l70:~/mail$ ls
inbox  #inbox#
```

What does the # mean in this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing special, it's just part of the file name!? You have a file that is named `#inbox#`!?